# Count total number of tab in Tabhost

Tags: java, android

How can I count total number of tabs in `tabhost` so that I can proceed for loop also how can I compare the `tabId` with selected `currenttab`. I am not able to set imageview visibility ontab change listener.

```
public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
{
    System.out.println("kkkkk" + tabId);
    System.out.println("lll" + mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()));

    for (int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("*****" + mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()));
        System.out.println("***" + tabId);

        if (tabId == mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()).toString())
        {
            imageontab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            imageontab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
getTabHost().getTabWidget().getTabCount()
```

This will return number of tabs..
documentation -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html#getTabCount()

(edit: fixed the anchor)

Answer (score 0):

You can get as below :

```
getTabHost().getTabWidget().getTabCount()
```